# Do modern browsers consistently inline functions? How can inlining be predicted for performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, inline

My question concerns modern browser optimization through function inlining. I think I really need someone who is familiar with the V8, JavaScriptCore, and/or SpiderMonkey codebase to answer this question; or at least someone knowledgeable in modern browser approaches to optimization.

Basically I want to know if there's any way to predict when function inlining will be used and how to leverage it for optimizing performance with minimal code duplication.

Let's take the following simple function from [joi](http://joijs.com/) tempo as an example:

```
function limit(f, max) {
    var count = 0, isFunction = typeof max == 'function';
    if(!isFunction) max = max >>> 0 || 1;
    return function limitedFunction() {
        if(isFunction ? !max(count) : (count >= max)) return;
        count++;
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

This function takes a function `f` and returns a wrapper function which limits the number of times the original function can be called through the wrapper. Example:

```
var foo = limit(function() { console.log('foo'); }, 3);
foo(); // logs 'foo'
foo(); // logs 'foo'
foo(); // logs 'foo'
foo(); // doesn't log anything
foo(); // doesn't log anything
```

It also accepts a function which returns `true` or `false` as its second argument (instead of a number):

```
var bar = limit(
    function() { console.log('bar'); },
    function() { return Math.random() > 0.5 ? true : false }
);
bar(); // randomly logs 'bar' or doesn't log anything
bar(); // randomly logs 'bar' or doesn't log anything
bar(); // randomly logs 'bar' or doesn't log anything
```

This is an overly simplistic, trivial example, so bear with me. I think there are real applications for this in non-trivial cases, but I want to use an easy case to get to the root of how the browser does or can do inlining.

One way to rewrite this function which could (probably) be (very slightly) improved for performance (I imagine) would be to separate the returned `function` into two cases, one where `max` is a function and the other where `max` is a number:

```
function limit(f, max) {
    var count = 0, isFunction = typeof max == 'function';
    if(!isFunction) max = max >>> 0 || 1;
    return isFunction
        ? function limitedFunctionA() {
            if(!max(count)) return;
            count++;
            return f.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        : function limitedFunctionB() {
            if(count >= max) return;
            count++;
            return f.apply(this, arguments);
        };
}
```

This way the check to see if `isFunction` is `true` or `false` doesn't have to occur *every time* `limitedFunction` is called but only once when it is determined whether to return `limitedFunctionA` or `limitedFunctionB`.  However, this is not ideal because there is some redundant code.

My question concerns the following rewrite:

```
function limit(f, max) {
    var count = 0, isFunction = typeof max == 'function',
        check = isFunction
            ? function() { return !max(count); }
            : function() { return count >= max; };
    if(!isFunction) max = max >>> 0 || 1;
    return function limitedFunction() {
        if(check()) return;
        count++;
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

So here's my question... **Will modern browsers be smart enough to turn**

```
if(check()) return;
```

**into**

```
if(!max(count)) return;
```

**when `isFunction` is true, and**

```
if(count >= max) return;
```

**when `isFunction` is false?** ... preventing the need to call the extra `check()` function, throwing an extra function onto the stack unnecessarily each time.

Comment: The answer might be eventually yes, (in particular when your `limit` function has been run many times), because modern browsers Javascript implementations usually do http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_just-in-time_compilation

Comment: I think in your third code you can write `check = max` if `isFunction` is true, and calling `check(count)` instead?

Comment: @Alvin The `max` function needs to be negated. The other function could be rewritten to return `count < max` and then check for `if(!check(count))` of course. But that's all beside the point, I think. This question's about browser optimizations for function inlining :)

Comment: @Basile, thanks for the Wikipedia article. Fascinating reading.

Comment: Do you just want to know out of iterest, or do you want to know specifically about a particular performance approach? I imagine there are many ways to optimise similar code (such as creating a minimal function object since *check* doesn't need scope or `[[Prototype]]` chains). So wher *check* is called or "inlined" is moot if you really just care about performance.

Comment: @RobG, are you saying there's no overhead in calling a function which the browser can determine doesn't need its own scope? I would think calling a function which could throw an error would have overhead because the console needs to show a stack trace. Would the browser optimize for functions which don't need their own scope + don't need to throw errors? (There may be other situations as well; that's just what I could think of off the top of my head.)

Comment: @RobG, to answer your question, primarily I am interested in performance, although curiosity plays a role as well.

Comment: This is a pretty heavy topic, but seriously, it's easier for the engine to optimize if you don't try to outsmart it. If you ***always*** pass the same value-type to a function, and you inline arrays, and don't mix values kept inside arrays (that also means using `31-bit signed int`s instead of floats), and don't add or remove properties from objects which aren't defined in the constructor (if you're going to template construction of objects -- an inline object will matter naught). These are places where big wins can be had in optimization without trying to outsmart the machine doing the work.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "off topic". It seems on topic to me... I read the FAQ, and it sure looks like it fits "software tools commonly used by programmers" and
"practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". It's not open ended, and it has a clear answer requiring an expert. Why can I go to find answers to these questions if not here?